# Support RTOS in Ubuntu 18.04 OS

Tags: kernel, realtime

I have installed Ubuntu 18.04 OS in my system, for configuring the Petalinux in my PC so that I can build real time application.
For that, I have some queries related to this.

1. How to enable realtime scheduling or realtime patch in Ubuntu Linux kernel?

Is any some thing we can enable in `menuconfig` of Ubuntu Linux kernel and build and run on the system.

Regards
Nithin

Comment: `CONFIG_PREEMPT` is probably what you're looking for on the kernel side.

Comment: how to select this. can u please tell me procedure for this

Comment: You can find the option under `General setup ---> Preemption model`. Alternatively you can press `/` and type 'PREEMPT' to search for it.